# Git : there are commits I did not create. How to get rid of those

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase

I always do a git pull --rebase even if I do not have a single pending commit.

I just did a pull.

Suddenly, when I run git status, I am seeing that my local master is 11 commits ahead of the remote master.

I dont know where they came from and want to get rid of them.

What do I do?

Comment: If in doubt, check `git log`.

Comment: @tkausl I am using it to best of my abilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that you're a victim of what is usually called an "upstream rebase".  You can jump right to the solution below but this background is pretty important.

#### Background

This why I hate `git pull`.  It's not `git pull`'s *fault*, really, but because `git pull` is a *convenience* command that simply runs `git fetch` followed by a second command, it winds up hiding the two underlying Git commands from new Git users.  The fact that there are two *different* second commands, *both of which can mess things up in different ways*, is spectacularly unhelpful.

Fortunately, the first part—the `git fetch` step—almost always works.<sup>1</sup>  It's the second step where, if all goes well, everyone says "oh that was easy" and thinks that `git pull` is great and then when it explodes, as it always does eventually, they're in trouble, because they have never had to deal with the second part failing.  And now it's an emergency and they have to spend a bunch of hours learning a bunch of complicated stuff: the way to recover from failures, and how merge and rebase interact with the `git fetch` step.

Anyway, this time you are the one stuck with the messy situation, so let's just press on with it.  The second half of what `git pull` does is either `git merge` or `git rebase`.  Exactly which command it does when is beyond the scope of this answer, except that we can say for sure that if you add `--rebase`, it *always* uses `git rebase`.  So you only have one complicated Git command to learn in a hurry.  (Yay? :-) )

Hence, as [Tim Biegeleisen answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39225566/1256452), these new mystery commits came from using `git rebase`.  So it's time now to learn all<sup>2</sup> about rebase, *and* **how it interacts with `git fetch`**.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are still a few ways it can go wrong, but usually the one that actually happens is "the network is down and thus we can't get anything from `origin`" which is really obvious and makes everything stop right at the beginning, and you just try again once the network is fixed.

<sup>2</sup>Well, let's not go *that* far. :-)

---

#### When fetch-and-rebase goes well

Rebase *can* be complicated but we can sum it all up very simply: `git rebase` copies commits.

That's it.  Rebase copies commits.  That's actually not bad at all, is it?  Well, it's not bad when they are *your* commits, but you just had it copy *someone else's commits*.  The tricky part here is defining precisely *which* commits get copied, when, and how.  This is where `git fetch` comes into the picture again.

Tim's drawing here covers the more normal case, when *you* have made some commits.  I'm going to make my own drawing though.  Let's say there are a bunch of commits, ending with a series `F--G--H`, when you start out.  That is, your `master` and `origin/master` both point to commit `H`, which points back to `G`, which points back to `F`, and so on.  You got all these when you did your initial `git clone` or your last `git pull --rebase` or whatever: it doesn't really matter how you got them, just that you do have them.

```
...--F--G--H      <-- master, origin/master
```

Now, normally, you might add your own commits, say `I` and `J`:

```
             I--J   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H        <-- origin/master
```

Meanwhile someone else, using their own Git, adds their own *different* commits.  You don't have them now.  Then they publish those commits, so now `origin` has them too.  You still don't!  But *now* you run `git fetch` and *now* you get them, and here's what happens in *your* repository.  Let's say they made just one commit, which we'll label `K`:

```
             I--J   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K      <-- origin/master
```

Note how the label, `origin/master`, has "moved forward" from `H` to `K`.  Meanwhile your own `master` is already moved forward from `H` to `J`: yours points to your commit `J`, which points back to your commit `I`, which points back to `H`.

This is where you normally bring `git rebase` in.  You ask it to copy your commits, `I` and `J`, to new commits that are "just as good" but are *based on* commit `K`:

```
             I--J   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H   I'-J'
            \ /
             K      <-- origin/master
```

Let's say the copy goes well, with no problematic merge conflicts and such.  You now have new commits that are *just like* your originals, except for their new "base" commit `K`.  That's a rebase!

All your Git has to do now is peel your `master` label off the old `J` and make it point to the new copied `J'`:

```
             I--J   [abandoned]
            /
...--F--G--H    I'-J'   <-- master
             \ /
              K      <-- origin/master
```

and now that the old commits are officially abandoned, we can straighten the whole picture out:

```
                I'-J'   <-- master
               /
...--F--G--H--K         <-- origin/master
```

#### When the rebase goes badly

There are multiple ways for `git rebase` to go awry.  Let's ignore some of them and just concentrate on the one that bit you.

Let's draw out more of the stuff that comes before `F--G--H` this time.  Also, you *didn't* have your own commits (you said, and I believe you).

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
```

Now, someone else did something upstream to "rebase", i.e., to *copy* some commits.  I don't know *exactly* what they did, but let's say they discovered that commit `D` was **D**efective, and perhaps even deleted it entirely.  They now have:

```
        D--E--F--G--H   [abandoned]
       /
A--B--C
       \
        E'-F'-G'-H'     <-- master
```

Now you run your `git fetch`.  What this does is to pick up their `master` and forcibly adjust your `origin/master` to match theirs.  So *you* still have `A-...-H` as usual, with your `master` pointing to that, but now you have `origin/master` pointing to `H'`:

```
        D--E--F--G--H   <-- master
       /
A--B--C
       \
        E'-F'-G'-H'     <-- origin/master
```

That's your `git fetch` step.  Now your `git pull` runs `git rebase`.  What rebase does, or tries to do, is to *copy* commits.  Which commits should it copy?  The answer here can get complicated, but to simplify things a lot, it will *think*, at this point, that `D--E--F--G--H` are *your* commits.  Those are the obvious copy candidates: they're the commits on *your* master, that are not on `origin/master`.

It *does* matter that `E'-F'-G'-H'` are copies themselves.  But let's just ignore that.  Whether your Git detects them as copies or not, your Git is *at least* going to *restore* commit `D`, thinking it's your work, rather than something that got stripped out.  In any case, because you're seeing 11 commits, your Git has somehow restored or resurrected or copied 11 commits.  Let's just draw all of `D`-through-`H` since our solution will be the same either way.

Your `git rebase` copies "your" commits (not really yours, it just thinks they're yours) and moves your `master` label, and you now have this:

```
        D--E--F--G--H   [abandoned]
       /
A--B--C             D'-E"-F"-G"-H"   <-- master
       \           /
        E'-F'-G'-H'     origin/master
```

Suddenly you're five commits "ahead of" `origin/master`.

#### Fixing it

***In this case***, since you're sure you really have no commits of your own, what you need to do is tell your Git to abandon all these new copies entirely.

The command that does all this for you is `git reset --hard`.  The thing about `git reset --hard` is that it *does* let you throw away a bunch of your own work, so you must be careful about when you use it.

In *this particular case*, though, you promised you had no commits of your own here.  Remember, it's just *this particular case*: no commits of your own, no uncommitted work in the work-tree, etc.  So it's safe to wipe things out.

So, what you want to do *in this case* is to tell your Git to move your `master` to point to the *same* commit as `origin/master`, abandoning all the copies that your `git rebase` made:

```
        D--E--F--G--H   [abandoned]
       /
A--B--C             D'-E"-F"-G"-H"   [abandoned]
       \           /
        E'-F'-G'-H'     <-- master, origin/master
```

If we now stop drawing in the abandoned commits, you'll see that your graph is now just:

```
A--B--C--E'-F'-G'-H'   <-- master, origin/master
```

which is what you want: you're no longer "ahead of" `origin/master`.

#### If you had commits of your own

Suppose, in all that mess, you really *did* have some commits to keep.  In this case, there are a bunch of ways to fix this, but probably the easiest is to use `git rebase -i` (interactive rebase: copy *selected* commits).  You can `git rebase -i` to get the 11 commits that Git *thinks* are yours into a set of instructions.  Then you delete, from the instruction sheet, all but the ones that really *are* yours, and your Git copies those yet again, and abandons the un-copied ones.

Since you promised there were no such commits, we were able to use the simpler `git reset --hard`.  (Depending on your Git version, we might *have to* use `reset`.  All versions of Git refuse to let you delete *everything* from the instruction sheet.  Newer versions let you put in a "no-op" instruction so that there's at least one instruction left, even if there are no copy instructions.)

Comment: Did a git reset --hard, Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont know where they came from

When you rebase your branch on the remote `master`, you are taking that remote branch and replaying all your local commits on top of the remote branch.  As such, it is a completely normal state for your local branch to be ahead of the remote.

> and want to get rid of them

These commits are quite possibly your own work.  Don't get rid of them!

Here is a diagram showing how rebasing works, so that you can see what is likely happening in your case.  Consider that both your local `master` and `origin/master` begin at the same commit:

```
origin: A
master: A
```

Now, you make say 3 commits while at the same time other people make 3 commits to the remote:

```
origin: A -- E -- F -- G
master: A -- B -- F -- D
```

If you now do a `git pull --rebase origin master` you will get the following:

```
origin: A -- E -- F -- G
master: A -- E -- F -- G -- B' -- F' -- D'
                            ^    ^^     ^^ these are your commits
```

In other words, after rebasing your local branch will appear as if you just cloned the remote and freshly committed all your work on top of it.  And in the example, rebasing has left your local branch 3 commits ahead of the remote.

Comment: I can see the author as a different person. I dont know if I should put a happy smiley or a sad smiley. so :|

Answer (score 0):

With git pull --rebase you get commits from the remote branch (master) that others pushed. But if you have commits that are not pushed to remote master, then status of git will refer that you local branch (master) is ahead of remote master for those commits.